# How to stop the loop from printing the *?

Tags: c++, function, loops, for-loop

I have created a project that breaks a big number to its roots, it works very well, but it prints an extra * at the end of the last root.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int multinum(int a, int b);
int primeOp(int a);

int main()
{
    char ch;
    do {
        int a=0, b=0;
        multinum(a,b);
        
        cout << "\n\nDo you want to continue?(y/n)";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch=='y');
    
return 0;
}

int multinum(int num1, int num2)
{
    cout<< "\nPlease enter the first number : ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the second number : ";
    cin >> num2;

    cout << num1 <<" = ";
    primeOp(num1);
    
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << num2 <<" = ";
    primeOp(num2);

    return 0;
}

int primeOp(int a)
{
   int i, x, power;

    x=a;

    if (a%2==0)
    {
        power=0 ;
        while(a%2==0)
        {
            a/=2;
            power++;
        }

        cout << 2 <<"^"<<power<< "*";
    }

    for (i=3; i<=x/2; i+=2)
    {
        power=0 ;
        while(a%i==0)
        {
            a/=i;
            power++;
        }

        if (power!=0)
            cout << i <<"^"<< power << "*";
            
        if (power!=0 && a%i== 0)
            cout << "*";
    }

    if(a==x)
        cout<< x << "^" << 1;


    return 0;
}
```

I tried to print * in different ways but none of them had any effect, I also tried to stop printing by the use of the last "i" or "power" but it was useless.

What should I do, to stop the * bring printed when it's not needed?

Example: 24 = 2^3 * 3^1 * --- it should become: 24 = 2^3*3^1

Comment: Asterisk should be printed BEFORE the next component, but only when some flag is set to true. You set the flag to true after you print a component.

Comment: I don't understand how a boolean might help here. :(

Comment: If you print a star *before* each element, except the first, you can use a boolean `is_first` to keep track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to print something only sometimes you need to print it under an `if`, and you need a condition that will control that print. A bool flag should do the trick. The other part of the trick is to print the asterisk before the next component, not after.

```
void PrintComponent(int root, int power, bool& printStar)
{
    if (printStar)
        cout << " * ";

    cout << root << "^" << power;
    printStar = true;
}

int primeOp(int a)
{
    int i, x, power;
    bool printStar = false;

    x = a;

    if (a % 2 == 0)
    {
        ...

        PrintComponent(2, power, printStar);
    }

    for (i = 3; i <= x / 2; i += 2)
    {
        ...

        if (power != 0)
            PrintComponent(i, power, printStar);
    }

    if (a == x)
        PrintComponent(x, 1, printStar);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If finding the last print is not easy make the first print special.

Print the first power like this:

```
cout << 2 <<"^"<<power;
```

Then print all the rest via

```
cout << "*2^"<<power;
```

I dont understand your code fully, but to know it is the first print you can use a boolean flag.

Comment: I don't understand how to use a boolean flag here. But if I alter the code as you said,it will generate an extra * at the beginning. 24 = *2^3*3^1

Comment: @Anonymous at the beginning of the function `bool firstprint = true;` then every time you print you check if it is the first and only when it is the first you print a `*`. After every printing you set `firstprint = false;`

Answer (score -2):

You can suppres this issue by printing backspaces at the end of the result.
In primeOp add:

```
cout <<"\b \b";
```

Just above return statement